# How to calculate the double sum of this formula?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$ \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{k=0}^N |k-n|$=?

Thanks for your consideration.

Add: Using help of P.Siehr I get this:

$$\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{k=0}^N |k-n| &= \sum_{n=0}^N \left [\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n-k) + \sum_{k=n+1}^N (k-n) \right ] \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^N \left (n^2 - \frac12 n (n-1) + \frac12 \left [N (N+1) - n (n+1) \right ] -n (N-n) \right )\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^N \left (\frac12 n (n+1) + \frac12 N (N+1) - \frac12 n (N+1) - n (N-n) \right)\\ &= \frac12 N (N+1)^2 - N \sum_{n=0}^N n + \sum_{n=0}^N n^2 \\& = \frac13 N (N+1) (N+2)\end{align}$$

Is it okay now?

Comment: Thanks for the hint of sieler. I do not know how to get rid of the absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Get rid of the absolute value by
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|i-j|= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{j=0}^i[...]+\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}[...]\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your help.\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{k=0}^N |k-n| &= \sum_{n=0}^N \left [\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n-k) + \sum_{k=n+1}^N (k-n) \right ] \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^N \left (n^2 - \frac12 n (n-1) + \frac12 \left [N (N+1) - n (n+1) \right ] -n (N-n) \right )\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^N \left (\frac12 n (n+1) + \frac12 N (N+1) - \frac12 n (N+1) - n (N-n) \right)\\ &= \frac12 N (N+1)^2 - N \sum_{n=0}^N n + \sum_{n=0}^N n^2 \\& = \frac13 N (N+1) (N+2)\end{align}

Comment: Seriously @steven ... don't write answer in comment...

Comment: Thanks for your kindly words. Please tell me where to write the answer?

Comment: Glad, that my hint helped you. You can simply formulate your solution as a (normal) answer. Mark that answer as correct, since it answers your question.  That way anyone (in the future) who has the same problem, will see your answer first. 

And, if you liked my hint, you can give my answer an upvote, as well. That is how this site works.

Comment: @MANMAID thanks for your help.

Comment: Almost the right way @steven. But write it as an answer, not as an edit of your question. (At the bottom of the page there is the "Add Another Answer" Button.

Answer (score 0):

Use $k\le n\implies |k-n|=n-k$, and split the inner summation.

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)+\sum_{k=n+1}^N(k-n)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)+\sum_{k=0}^N(k-n)-\sum_{k=0}^n(k-n)\right)\\
=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(2\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)+\sum_{k=0}^N(k-n)\right).$$

Then by the Faulhaber formulas,

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(2n(n+1)-n(n+1)+\frac{N(N+1)}2-n(N+1)\right)\\
=\frac{N(N+1)(N+2)}3.$$

Comment: thanks for your excellent answer.